# How can I iterate through an excel sheet to perform a search on a webpage Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, iteration

I want to iterate through a list of companies to search them one by one and save the href.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html 
import time
import requests 
df=pd.read_excel('/Users/ap/companies.xlsx')
browser = Firefox(options=opts)
browser.get('https://webpage')
search_form=browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_frmEntityName')
i=0
for i in df['company_name']:
    search_form.send_keys(i)
    search_form_buttom=browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit').click()
#wait a bit to make this element work.search_form.send_keys('BioHealth')
    time.sleep(15)
    i=i+1
```

I get the following error and I'm not able to sort it out, before even being able to **scrape** the hrefs.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-e157420a273e> in <module>()
     21 #wait a bit to make this element work.search_form.send_keys('BioHealth')
     22     time.sleep(10)
---> 23     i=i+1
     24 

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

Comment: In your for loop, you are shadowing the integer i that you have before the for loop. Please change the for a variable to something more meaningful name. It seems to be a string value indicating company name

Comment: But how can I iterate through all the companies in the excel sheet one after another in the column df['companies'] and search for them one by one with search_form.send_keys() ??

Comment: But how can I iterate through all the companies in the excel sheet one after another in the column df['companies'] and search for them one by one with search_form.send_keys() ??

Comment: what is the purpose of the i = 0; before the for loop, and the spurious i = i+1 inside the loop?  Remove those two lines, and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop assignes the strings found in `df['company_name']` to it's variable `i`. At the end of the loop you add `1` to this string, which is not allowed, as the python interpreter can not implicitly cast an int to a string.

I have the feeling, that you are trying to use the `i=i+1` as a loop counter variable, but that is not needed in a for-each-loop (i.e. `for i in foo`). Just delete that `i=i+1`. The loop will still run as expected.

However, if you really want to add a one to the string stored in `i`, you have to write it like this:
`i=i+str(1)`
Then the python interpreter will accept it.